# Find duplicate from list and sum

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
data = [(0, 0, {'product_id': 6, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 8, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 7, 'qty': 2.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 6, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 8, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 7, 'qty': 2.0})]
```

I have this list, What i want to do is to find repeted product id and sum theire qty and remove duplicate product id elelment from list

Output of list should be:

```
 new_data = [(0, 0, {'product_id': 6, 'qty': 2.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 8, 'qty': 2.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 7, 'qty': 4.0})]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to build a dictionary (map) for your product ids, extract your data into that dictionary, then build your new data list. Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def mergeQty(data):
  qtyMap = defaultdict(float)
  for x, y, product in data:
    id = product['product_id']
    qty = product['qty']
    qtyMap[(x, y, id)] += qty

  return [(x, y, { 'product_id' : id, 'qty' : qty }) for (x, y, id), qty in qtyMap.iteritems()]
```

Note that this will *not* merge products whose first two values differ (in your example they are all 0's, and we can only guess at what those mean).

**EDIT:** Thanks Azat for `defaultdict` suggestion.

**EDIT:** Keeping unknown fields `x` and `y` intact as per kuro's suggestion.

Comment: how about `qtyMap = defaultdict(float)`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I was blissfully unaware of defaultdict. Edited, thanks :)

Comment: Your answer works for the sample data given. But it would be better if you don't populate the tuple with hardcoded 0 as first 2 elements. You can simply use `(x, y, id)` as the key to `qtyMap` and change the list comprehension accordingly

Comment: @kuro Good idea. Changed. Although it's unclear if OP would want them to merge if x, y differ.  I'm sure he/she can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

one line solution:

```
data = [(0, 0, {'product_id': 6, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 8, 'qty': 1.0}),
        (0, 0, {'product_id': 7, 'qty': 2.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 6, 'qty': 1.0}),
        (0, 0, {'product_id': 8, 'qty': 1.0}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 7, 'qty': 2.0})]

import itertools
import functools
from operator import itemgetter

[functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0], x[1], {'product_id': x[2]['product_id'], 'qty': x[2]['qty'] + y[2]['qty']}), y) for _,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: itemgetter('product_id')(itemgetter(2)(x))),key=lambda x: itemgetter('product_id')(itemgetter(2)(x)))]
```

Comment: nice one line code but its difficult to break down.